# Xcode 7.3 AutoCode is not working normally

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

Basically its not auto completing the code.  i have also deleted the derived data of Xcode than also Auto code is not working.

it should work like this
[image: Normal case]

But it is working like this
[image: Not Normal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051):

> Code completion enhancements in the Xcode source editor help you enter symbols, methods, and property names with less typing. Code completion now provides more intelligent suggestions by using partial matches and the first letter of each word, in addition to prefix matching.

Comment: So that means i cant change that in setting.

Comment: You mean like, "Thanks for the new feature, Apple, and now how the heck do I turn this off"? That would be nice, wouldn't it? But Apple doesn't usually work that way. They are more like "We know what's best for you so shut up and like it." File a bug report if you want a preference...